# setCollideWorldBounds(true) is not a function, using Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Using Phaser 3, I'm trying to use `setCollideWorldBounds`, but its always telling me that isn't a function. I had already add physics to the game and it still doesn't work.

```
window.onload = function() {
config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    scene: [Scene, Scene2],
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
          gravity: { y: 200 },
          enableBody: true,
        }
    }
}
var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
}

create() {
    this.background = this.add.tileSprite(0,0,800,500,"space");
    this.background.setOrigin(0,0);
    this.spaceship = this.add.sprite(0,Phaser.Math.Between(1,width),"spaceship");
    this.player_spaceship = this.add.sprite(400,250,"player_spaceship");
    this.scoreText = this.add.text(16,16, 'score: 0', { fontSize: '32px', fill: 'red' });
    this.keys = this.input.keyboard.addKeys("W,A,S,D");
    this.anims.create ({
        key: "player_spaceship", //name of the animation
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers("player_spaceship"), //takes the spritesheet
        frameRate:20, // frames per seconds
        repeat: -1 // repeat infinite
    });
    this.player_spaceship.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
    this.spaceship.play("player_spaceship");
    this.player_spaceship.play("player_spaceship");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

setCollideWorldBounds is a method on the Arcade Body and (for convenience) the Arcade Sprite classes. Unfortunately, it isn't a method on the sprite class itself, which is what your code is using.

#### 1. Vanilla sprites

You *can* use "vanilla" sprites and later add physics to them:

```
// Assumes the `create` method was snipped from a Scene class
this.player_spaceship = this.add.sprite(400, 250, "player_spaceship");
this.physics.world.enable(this.player_spaceship);
this.player_spaceship.body.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
// nit: don't add me to any physics groups below this line, or I'll forget you want me to collide with the world bounds! Weird but true.
```

#### 2. Arcade sprites

Alternatively, you can also just use the physics classes & factories to hide a little bit of this complexity from yourself:

```
this.player_spaceship = this.physics.add.sprite(400, 250, "player_spaceship");
this.player_spaceship.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
// You *could* use the body here instead if you wanted! But since you have the convenience method, might as well use it.
```

#### Which way is better?

Eh. Probably way number 2. Depends on your game.